# Proving $f$ is convex IFF for every compact subinterval and every affine function $L$, $\sup(f+L)$ is at an endpoint

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-analysis

Specifically, I am wondering if this proof **requires** that the second part is true for **every** compact subinterval, or whether it just needs to be true for an affine function that agrees with $f$ at endpoints.

To fully state what theorem I'm talking about :

> Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on an interval $I$. then $f$ is convex IFF for every compact subinterval $j$ of $I$, and every affine function $L$, the supremum of $f+L$ is attained at an endpoint,

And to restate the question:

- does the result require this to be true for EVERY affine function $L$,?
- If it is not required, why is it included?

---